# Text not appearing on SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to create an `svg` element on my webpage with text. I'm building the `svg` using Javascript, but for some reason the text will not show up. I've read a bunch of questions about this and I'm still clueless.

code:

```css
.but {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

 .svg-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#bus {
    z-index: -100;
    transform-box: view-box;
    transform-origin: center;
}

#busProps {
    fill: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="svg-container" id="svgPlace"></div>

    <button id="create" class="but" onclick=createSVG()>Click to create bus</button>
    <button id="drawFool" class="but" onclick=changeColor()>Click to change color</button>
    <button id="rotateBus" class="but" onclick=rotate()>Rotate</button>

    <script>
        const colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"];
        let index = 0;
        let currentRot = 0;

        function createSVG() {
            let markerContainer = document.getElementById('svgPlace');
            let markerSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('id', 'bus');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 512 512');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('height', '50px');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('width', '100px');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: -100; text-align: center');

            let busPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
            busPath.setAttribute('id', 'busProps');
            busPath.setAttribute('d', 'M480 358.856V153.143C480 130.512 461.674 112 439.272 112H72.728C50.326 112 32 130.512 32 153.143v205.713C32 381.488 50.326 400 72.728 400h366.545C461.674 400 480 381.488 480 358.856zM112 364V148h288v216H112z');
            busPath.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFFFF');

            let text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
            text.setAttribute('id', 'busNum');
            text.setAttribute('x', '175');
            text.setAttribute('y', '250');
            text.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFFFF');
            text.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 1;')
            text.textContent = '25';

            markerSvg.appendChild(busPath);
            markerSvg.appendChild(text);
            markerContainer.appendChild(markerSvg);
        }

        function colorize(customColor) {
            document.getElementById("busProps").style.fill = customColor;
        }

        function changeColor() {
            index = (index + 1) % 4;
            colorize(colors[index]);
        }

        function rotate() {
            let rotBus = document.getElementById("bus");
            currentRot = (currentRot + 45) % 360;
            let rotString = "rotate(" + currentRot + ")";
            rotBus.setAttribute("transform", rotString);
        }
    </script>
```

Some things I've tried are changing the width attribute of the text element, changing the font size of the text element, and messing around with the x/y placement of the text element. The current x/y settings have the text where I should be able to at least see a part of it ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyovS.png)). I'm lost on what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got white text on a white background, so there's that. Also it just looks like the text was so small that you couldn't see it.
If you set the font size you can make it visible.

`text.setAttribute('font-size', '200');`

Tweaked some things, but I imagine you can take it from here to make it look how you'd like.

```css
.but {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

 .svg-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#bus {
    z-index: -100;
    transform-box: view-box;
    transform-origin: center;
}

#busProps {
    fill: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="svg-container" id="svgPlace"></div>

    <button id="create" class="but" onclick=createSVG()>Click to create bus</button>
    <button id="drawFool" class="but" onclick=changeColor()>Click to change color</button>
    <button id="rotateBus" class="but" onclick=rotate()>Rotate</button>

    <script>
        const colors = ["blue", "green", "red", "yellow"];
        let index = 0;
        let currentRot = 0;

        function createSVG() {
            let markerContainer = document.getElementById('svgPlace');
            let markerSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('id', 'bus');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 512 512');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('height', '50px');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('width', '100px');
            markerSvg.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: -100; text-align: center');

            let busPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
            busPath.setAttribute('id', 'busProps');
            busPath.setAttribute('d', 'M480 358.856V153.143C480 130.512 461.674 112 439.272 112H72.728C50.326 112 32 130.512 32 153.143v205.713C32 381.488 50.326 400 72.728 400h366.545C461.674 400 480 381.488 480 358.856zM112 364V148h288v216H112z');
            busPath.setAttribute('fill', '#FFFFFF');

            let text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
            text.setAttribute('id', 'busNum');
            text.setAttribute('x', '160');
            text.setAttribute('y', '320');
            text.setAttribute('fill', '#000000');
            text.setAttribute('font-size', '200');
            text.setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 1;');
            text.textContent = '25';

            markerSvg.appendChild(busPath);
            markerSvg.appendChild(text);
            markerContainer.appendChild(markerSvg);
        }

        function colorize(customColor) {
            document.getElementById("busProps").style.fill = customColor;
        }

        function changeColor() {
            index = (index + 1) % 4;
            colorize(colors[index]);
        }

        function rotate() {
            let rotBus = document.getElementById("bus");
            currentRot = (currentRot + 45) % 360;
            let rotString = "rotate(" + currentRot + ")";
            rotBus.setAttribute("transform", rotString);
        }
    </script>
```